# How to make a box with the minimal height and vertical alignment inside the box?

Tags: vertical-alignment, parbox

I need to set minimal table (one-row table) height, and valign content inside it. For this prupose i wrap `tabular` in `parbox` in tabular i have  correct `valign`, and parbox gives me min height.

My question is - how to valign table in parbox (or to make it with me minipage, but then - how to make a min height)?

Here is the example code (it's the same in prev question :) ) :
how to valign table (here it's in the header)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[left=72pt,right=72pt,
    headheight=124pt,
    top=\dimexpr124pt+\headsep\relax,% <- added
    textheight =540pt
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}


\newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \sbox{0}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{tabular}{@{}L{\textwidth}{p}@{}}Non-disclosure agreement (NDA)\end{tabular}}}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0<124pt \dp0\dimexpr124pt-\ht0\fi
  \makebox{\usebox{0}}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Due to comments: common task is to make a table with one raw and several columns and valign-halign and fixed minimal height. 
In my example i use only one column to make task less complicated

Comment: your question isn't that clear, why do you need the parbox at all? it does not seem to be doing anything, also a one-column, one row tabular isn't doing anything useful either. Could you state what is the intended effect of the code?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Parbox sets the height (minmal) to 124. all "unuseful" code - is due to automatic generation. I generate all automaticly - so this one-cell table is a particular case. I have more complicated examples, but it will be the same issue ) In common i need a table (one-raw) with the fixed minimal height and valign.

Comment: No, parbox does have an optional argument to set its height but you are not using that.  I honestly can not guess what this code is intended to do, not only the parbox and tabular (which does not do anything very much other than box the text `Non-disclosure agreement`) but also the setting of the depth of the box afterwards.  perhaps you just want  `\fancyhead[C]{\rule{0pt}{124pt}Non-disclosure agreement (NDA)}`  but I really can not guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle usually there is a two or three columns. (In the example - only one cell with the small text). In each cell there must be valign and halign and fixed minimal height. So just \rule can't make it.

Comment: Min height in parbox - works ok, i don't know how ))) i'm not good in latex, i just found an example here, and make the same - it works. May be there is a better decision. But i don't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[left=72pt,right=72pt,
    headheight=124pt,
    top=\dimexpr124pt+\headsep\relax,% <- added
    textheight =540pt
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}


\newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  %\raisebox{\dimexpr\headheight-\height}[\headheight][0pt]% top alignment
  %\raisebox{0pt}[0.5\headheight][0.5\headheight]% middle alignment
  \raisebox{\depth}[\headheight][0pt]% bottom alignment
  {\begin{tabular}{@{}L{\textwidth}{p}@{}}
  Non-disclosure agreement (NDA)\\
  %a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\\j\\k\\l
  \end{tabular}}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: So there is no vertical alignment in your answer, i need vertical alignment by middle or bottom

Comment: bottom for example. When i put {\begin{tabular}{@{}L{\textwidth}{b}@{}} it doesn't  works

Comment: [b] should go first.  Anyway, \raisebox moves the baseline where it belongs.