# Which component to use: provides few columns, page-breakable, valign, minimun height?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have got so much help on this site in my particular tasks, and now i realize i'm using something wrong for my purpose.

I need a decision (component, or a set of the components), that provides few columns, page-breakable, valign/halign, minimun height, and no paragraph spacing between components.
here [How to make a box with the minimal height and vertical alignment inside the box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366966/how-to-make-a-box-with-the-minimal-height-and-vertical-alignment-inside-the-box) I've got a good answer, for the header. But it doesn't work with `longtable`, so doesn't supports page breaking.

May be i need to use not table - but some combination of boxes for this purpose?

Example, user makes a template like this:
[image]

I take the template, take the text from DB and put in in the same order as user wants.

So i don't know how much text it will be in the layout. 
Now i have a working version using `longtables`. Minimum height i provide with `\parbox` (if data is short and layout is high). But then i have a problem with valign - how to valign table in parbox?
If the text in layout is bigger - layout should be stretched for sure and breaked to pages.

I use such constuction now (each row in the teplate - one parbox with longtable), it doesn't provides page breaking and not valigned:

Example:
I have a template:[image]

And i'v got such resulting PDF (the text is not valigned, and it has big paragraph space, so begins not from top): [image]

Code that i use is following:

```
 \documentclass{book}
            \usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
            \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
            \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
            \usepackage{graphicx}
            \usepackage{fixltx2e}
            \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
            \usepackage[left=72pt,right=72pt,
                headheight=72pt,
                top=\dimexpr72pt+\headsep\relax,
                textheight =592pt
                ]{geometry}
            \usepackage{array}
            \usepackage{longtable}
            \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

            \newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash \hspace{0pt}}{#2}{#1}}
            \newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}
            \newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\center\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}
            \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[C]{\raisebox{\dimexpr\headheight-\height}[\headheight][0pt] {\begin{tabular}{L{\textwidth}{p}}Non-disclosure agreement (NDA)\end{tabular}}}\begin{document}
            \pagestyle{fancy}
             \noindent\sbox{0}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\noindent\begin{longtable}{C{\textwidth}{m}}Text\end{longtable}}}
        \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0<517pt
        \dp0\dimexpr517pt-\ht0\fi
        \makebox{\usebox{0}}\\ \noindent\sbox{0}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\noindent\begin{longtable}{L{\textwidth}{p}}Text\end{longtable}}}
        \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0<27pt
        \dp0\dimexpr27pt-\ht0\fi
        \makebox{\usebox{0}}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. i'm creating automatic generation of the latex doc. there is some UI,  where user creates template for the data. I take the template, take the data from DB, and put data in template ) . So if user makes a layout 120 pt height, and i've got data only to fill 20 pt. Layout still must be 120 pt, and data should be aligned vertically. Layout may have 2-3columns. Layout can be placed in header or document body.

Comment: I need the same decision for the page content also, for the header i already have, now need foe the page content

Comment: Part of the page, layout is placed one after another

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see the question update

Comment: Thanks for the update that makes the question a lot more likely to get an answer:-) I'll delete my earlier comments.  (I can't answer until the evening probably but someone else probably will answer  before then)

Comment: Possibly use coffins? If you are putting things precisely on the page. But I don't understand how page breaking is supposed to come into it. Can you post an example?

Comment: Things are not precisely on the page, it placed one after another. How much pages takes each - is unknown before. I have a layout(section/box) - on my picture it has dotted border - and put data into it. It can happen that there will two words of data - or few pages. So layout should stretched on few pages, or keep the min height. Longtable gives me all i want, except minimum table height.  Parbox wrapping makes me stack on valign. see the question update

Comment: Since you already have a partial solution, please post it in the form of compilable code i.e. a complete minimal document showing the problem. Otherwise, answers are unlikely to mesh well with what you are currently happy with.

Comment: For example, I thought you were using the `\parbox` within the table, but then you say you're putting the table in a `\parbox`. But that obviously will prevent page breaks, so there is no point in using `longtable` in this case.

Comment: I'm sorry my knowleges in latex is poor, so i don't understand clearly how does all it work. Now i see it's really not page-breakable. So how to make this task correct? One more example i put in the question.